# Android: Sending group SMS with built in SMS app

Tags: android, android-intent, smsmanager

So I have an application that takes a array of phone numbers. I was told to make an sms intent that would send out group texts by being given a string in the form of: "123456789; 123456789; 123456789; ..."
The application works in the Android Studio emulator and can send the message but when tested on a device it crashes when it starts the activity.
The application can send out one system.out.println right before it starts the intent, so it doesnt crash before it. Whats happening?

```
public void sendDialogIntent() {
    String numbersToBeUsed = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (numbersToBeUsed.isEmpty()) {
            numbersToBeUsed = values[i].number;
        } else {
            numbersToBeUsed = numbersToBeUsed + "; " + values[i].number;
        }

    }
    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.putExtra("address", numbersToBeUsed);
    i.putExtra("sms_body", constructTextMessage());
    i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    System.out.println(numbersToBeUsed);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

//Values is an array of a class that has a string called number
//the first part of the method is taking these numbers in the values array and turning them into the phone number string, numbersToBeUsed
//constructTextMessage just gives you a String

Comment: what shown in logcat?

Comment: When I test it in the emulator, when it does the startActivity(), it says this:
2497-2497/com.prototype.myname.test I/System.out﹕ 9524546271; 6513220523; 1337 ... I mean it is in the same form that the example I was given was in, so I figured if I just exchanged the numbers I'd be O.K.

Comment: no, i mean the log when your app crash. not your system out